# Как сверстать у кого-то есть идеи?

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Задача следующая... Есть картинка размерами 1000*768 пикселей... Надо при наведении на некоторые объекты чтоб они подсвечивались... Причем дизайнер нарисовал так что там идет не просто подсветка а ещё и добавление некоторых элементов + выводится подпись... Выкладываю 2 картинки до наведения и что после наведения... Может кто подскажет хорошее решение...

[image]

[image]

Верстать просто дивами неполучится потому что объекты не ровные и налазить друг на друга будут... Уже думал с идеей создать тег <map> и на каждый <area> повесить событие onmouseover и он onmouseout и на эти события делать прозрачным непрозрачным...

И как сделать всплывающие подсказки такими как нарисованы полупрозрачные...

Вообщем ничего путнего не получилось... Может кто-то делал такие нестандартные верстки???

Вот ссылка на которой можно посомтреть ДЕМКА как щас сделано... http://demo.versal.cn.ua/

Comment: Попробуйте: воспользоваться map и в аrеа в параметр alt положить div

Comment: А Flash'ем?

Answer (score 2):

Блок с картинкой размещаешь с позиционированием `relative`, в него, допустим, фоном ставишь картинку свою. Далее внутри создаешь блоки со всплывающими подсказками, внутри размещаешь рамку и текст. Позиционируешь их абсолютно, расставляешь как положено. Стилями поставь им `disblay:none`. Далее при наведении курсора на любой из этих блоков вызываешь обработчик события `onMouseOver` и показываешь блок `show();`. Если же без яваскриптов, то в css - `div:hover{display:block;}`. И будет счастье)

Comment: яж написал... края не ровные у картинок... получится что если навести на фонарь - то подсветится и газон... потому как блок фонаря будет поверх блока с газоном... Так что такой вариант врядли прокатит...

Comment: Да отличный вариант! Не обязательно весь газон подсвечивать, делается просто небольшой участок, реагирующий на наведение, а что уже потом подсвечивать - дело третье. @Barton дал дельный совет!

Comment: Всеравно чего-то не пойму... надо же чтоб подсвечивался весь элемент на который наведешь... Наведение происходит на div по его совету... Его способом получится что наводишь рядом с газоном возле фонтана.. в выямке... а подсветится газон потому что это его ещё кусок идет... неправильно это помоему...

Comment: ну если не ровные то рисуй map, вешай айдишники и по ним показывай блоки с подсказками, но я думаю что все же такие дивы, как я написал каши тебе не испортят

Comment: испортят испортят... по крайней мере в данной ситуации... будет котовасия с наведением...

Answer (score 0):

Озвучу погромче идею, которая уже прозвучала:
[Карта рисунка](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) спасет мир. Поищите редактор карт(например, такой есть в Dreamweaver), чтобы не подгонять координаты. 
Смысл: на изображении есть области любой формы, которые являются активными.

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />

 <map name="planetmap">
   <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" />
   <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" />
   <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus" />
 </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну если map и div не подходит, тогда только flash. Имхо идеальный вариант!

Comment: ну смотрите... Если ставить div сразу на место где он должен появится с парамитрами display:none; то сразу карта перестает быть нужной потому что тот div идет поверх и он не просвечивается... получается надо поставить фон, поверх разместить div с display:none - и уже в этом диве провести на новой картинке map. получается надо 2 раза map делать... на фон и на внутренние дивы...

Answer (score 0):

Как еще вариант, можете воспользоваться canvas'ом и библиотекой [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) ([пример](http://raphaeljs.com/github/impact.html)). Хотя это получится тот же map.